# How to install a newer/different libc6 version?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 *focal fossa*.

I'm trying to install a package that depends on `libc6=<2.33` or above. However, focal repositories [only have version 2.31](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libc6), which is causing dependency troubles:

```
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is to be installed
```

**Is there any way I can install `libc6` 2.34 or above on Ubuntu 20.04 *focal*?**

```
$ apt-cache policy libc6
  Installed: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Candidate: 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's a good technical question for advanced explorers! Most folks who discover this question should keep in mind that the whole point of an LTS release is that the software doesn't change. Once you start changing basic elements deep in the stack, it's not really LTS anymore...regardless of the label. Most folks who want to run newer software should try a tested, stable 6-month release of Ubuntu instead of frankensteining an older LTS release.

Comment: I would not do it if I was you. libc is a  library touching so many core packages. I would upgrade your system to 22.04  See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379732/dpkg-regarding-libc6-2-34-wont-install-because-itd-break-locales-2-34-and "install a package"  what package? Because I would assume there is also a 20.04 version of that package.  You could install virtualbox, 22.04 in that and that package in that system as a workaround

Comment: and another one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143268/how-to-install-a-libc6-version-2-29 with the advice to not do it. Please be accurate and name the package. Maybe there is a snap version :)

Comment: Are you SERIOUS to leave the vulnerable libc 2.31 with the system just for whatsoever about LTS release? It IS even worse to make a comment here, man.

Comment: @Rinzwind It should be totally fine to install libc to a different path, and then use [patchelf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44710599/712526) to adjust the executable that won't run. Is there no way to install another libc with the alternate system in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Y.Z Note the distro suffix `-0ubuntu9.2`. glibc point releases won't stay _completely still_ after release. It is a very common practice for packagers to backport fixes, including security fixes, from later versions or even the git master, so the security concerns simply do not exist with an up-to-date system.